# Get the time information of recorded frames (Android)

Tags: android, android-camera

I would like to obtain exact information (with precision of at least 1 ms.) on the time at which recorded frames were captured. Assuming that I know the constant framerate, I could do with just the time of the first frame. 
Currently, I am recording:

```
mMediaRecorder.start();
mRecordingStartTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

but I suppose that there might be some delay between this moment and the moment of capturing the first frame.

I am thinking of getting a callback on frames. I do not think there is a callback on MediaRecorder, but I think there is one on preview. If the preview knew that recording has started (by checking a flag), it could recognize the first frame and call `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` then or read a timestamp if available. Does this approach make sense or would you suggest a different one?

Comment: Could you provide some more context as to why you want to accomplish this and why you need such accurate time stamps? Your approach seems like a valid one (at least I don't see a better way of doing this), however, if you want to compare these times to say the presentation time stamps (PTS) of the recorded video at a later time, it isn't going to work.

Comment: I need to synchronize recorded video with another process taking place at the same time, specifically GPS location.

Comment: It is most likely not possible to get 1ms precision. The encoder is going to take some arbitrary amount of input frames and take some arbitrary amount of time to produce the first output frames. On playback you cannot assume a fixed duration of frames, some might be slightly long or shorter, but it averages to some frame rate. You should be able to synchronize the PTS of the first frame with your record start time and get close, but not 1ms. Also, I assume your GPS time stamps are at 1Hz anyway, which means interpolation and an even larger error.

Comment: I am not concerned about the playback so much. Suppose, that I implement Camera.PreviewCallback and check time from the system clock at onPreviewFrame(). How close it is to the time the image was taken from the sensor? (or can I get a better precision?). If I set a flag indicating starting of recording, will I be able to identify the first recorded frame correctly when reading this flag at onPreviewFrame()?

Comment: The time from when you start feeding frames into a encoder and the time that it takes to produce the first encoded frame is going to be different for each device, codec and whatever it is you are filming. It will not be anywhere close to 1ms, however. On the other hand, if you are trying to show the location of where video was filmed based on GPS, being within a second should be totally acceptable. The GPS has location error, it is slow and I am not aware of a way to precisely ( < 1ms) associate encoded video to GPS timestamps.